# Passing an array of objects to ng-init using EJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ejs

I am using nodeJs with expressJS and EJS as my render engine. Inside my index.js, I did this:

```
//index.js
app.get('/user/checklist/', function(req, res) {
var data = {
    checklist: [{
        title: "Announce your engagement",
        body: "Congratulations, you are engaged! Spread the word using #JustSaidYes or try these fun ways to announce your engagement."
    }]
}
     res.render('checklist', { data: data });    
});
```

I am trying to pass the array of objects from the render method to ng-init inside my checklist.ejs so I did this:

```
 <!--checklist.ejs -->
<div ng-controller="CheckListCtrl" ng-init='items= <%- data.checklist %>'>
<div class="clearfix nservice-cancel-wrapper">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to initialise my items variable with the array of objects so I can later loop through it later down my program. But it is not working and the error messages I am getting is:

```
[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 17 of the expression [items= [[object Object]]]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<%= data.checklist %>` ?

Comment: @wrangler That doesn't work either

Comment: I think its problem with json parse as javaScript, by default, doesn't JSON-encode objects when converting them to strings, so you have to do that manually (you can use angular.toJson(object) for this) same issue here: https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms/issues/13.

Comment: @wrangler actually problem is the other way. Needs to be stringified in template

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place? Make a `$http` request to get that items data

Comment: So do it in a service and inject that service wherever it is needed

Comment: @charlietfl does it mean it is not possible using the above method I tried without using $http. I am trying to avoid unnecessary request.

Comment: Not impossible. Just not usual to need to do it using ng-init. You need to stringify `data.checklist` though to print it in template